# Finite morphisms between two varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, configuration-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be varieties in some projective space. Furthermore let's assume these two varieties are intersecting at the subvariety $Z$. For this problem we are assuming that $\text{dim}(X)\ll\text{dim}(Y)$. When is it possible to extend the identity morphism on $Z$ to a finite morphism from $X$ to $Y$?

Originally the problem was stated in a way that $Y=\text{Sym}^{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^d)$ and $X$ was a subvariety of $\text{Sym}^{n}(\mathbb{P}^d)$ (you can assume the projective space is the projective space that $\text{Sym}^{n}(\mathbb{P}^d)$ is embedded into by the Whitney-Segre embedding for Chow varieties), but it was downvoted so I decided to change the statement of the problem to more general question.

Motivation: This came up as I was trying to understand divisible elements in Morphic cohomology. For example if you remove a point from projective space you can project everything down to a hyperplane. Thus if you have a high codimension subvariety $X$ you can find the finite morphism described above when $Y$ is a hyperplane. This can lead to a new proof of Suslin's conjecture for weight one Morphic cohomology. Weight one Morphic cohomology is about the topology of algebraic maps from a smooth variety to projective spaces. The maps described in the first paragraph give us transfer like morphisms which proves there cannot be any non-torsion (infinitely) divisible elements in weight one Morphic cohomology. This together with Bloch-Kato implies the Suslin's conjecture for weight one. (There is another approach for weight one which is basically direct calculation but I am trying to find a different approach.)

Now I was thinking whether this approach has any chance of getting generalized to all higher weights. In that case you would need a projection-like finite morphism from a high codimension subvariety of $\text{Sym}^{n}(\mathbb{P}^d)$ to $\text{Sym}^{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^d)$. So I am not sure if something like this exists or when it exists.

Weight one Morphic cohomology groups cannot have non-torsion infinitely divisible elements. If this turns out to be true for higher weights (it could be wrong) then it implies Suslin's conjecture for all weights. Suslin's conjecture also implies all Grothendieck's standard conjectures in char 0 (This is the ultimate motivation I can give).

Comment: It might help to explain the motivation for this problem. Right now I would say the answer is "usually not, but sometimes".

Comment: @WillSawin I had written motivation but removed it, I'll add it back.